# Under purpose? On purpose?

Tags: prepositions

> I don't think Nikki would have hurt your feelings under/on purpose.

The key is **under**. Is it correct or is it a mistake in printing?

Comment: The idiom is on purpose. Under purpose isn't idiomatic.

Comment: *I don't think Nikki would have hurt your feelings purposely!*

Comment: I'm surprised we didn't hear *under-purposed* in the business world to mean someone who needs a promotion!

Answer (score 2):

It's an idiomatic mistake. The colloquial turn of phrase is "on purpose." It's not really a grammatical issue since both "under purpose" and "on purpose" are both (virtually identical) prepositional phrases.

There are tangentially related phrases that use "under," however. Example:

> I don't think Nikki would have hurt your feelings under false pretenses.